# Data drift on Row-Based-Replication

Tags: mysql, replication, data-synchronization, percona-tools

i've realized that one of my mysql slaves has missing rows.
select count on specific table on master:
9605010
on slave:
9593831

slave is completely sync,
no seconds_behind_master,
no errors,
no slow log

version on both master and slaves:
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.35-80.0, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  6.3

sync_binlog=1,
row-based-replication

i'm not sure about using pt-table-checksum because, this is a prod system.
What could be cause the data drift on rbr anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to tell without investigation. Potentially it could be mistakes when you created the slave, it could be direct writes to the slave, bugs in replication, bugs in an app with `SET binlog=0`, etc.

Worse, it's very hard to investigate post-factum. You need to prepare for the data drift troubleshooting.

`pt-table-checksum` would be your first step. It's a mature tool, safe to use on prod, but problems are possible, too. Most likely, locking issues, deadlocks. If need to be extra paranoid, I set `--chunk-time` to something like 0.1 or even less.

Find differences in the data, review it (you may want to use [twindb_table_compare](https://github.com/twindb/twindb_table_compare) to find which rows are missing/extra/different), and fix the mismatches (with `pt-table-sync` or rebuild the slave depending how big the data drift is).

And put `pt-table-checksum` in cron. If one run takes long time (say 1 - 2 days) I recommend to split discovery and alerting parts (i.e. the heavy `pt-table-checksum` populates `percona`.`checksums` and a light script checks `percona`.`checksums` and alerts if inconsistencies are found). On my systems I run `pt-table-checksum` continuously.

Then, when an inconsistency is discovered inspect the data, the binlog and then you'll figure out where it comes from.

Comment: Thank you for great explanation. I am curious about using pt-table-checksum on row based system. Some people say this is ok but limitations on percona documantation is confusing me. For example if i use the tool, would master binlog switch to statement based? if it is yes what are the expected results

Comment: It sets binlog format to STATEMENT in its session. So it'll work even if you use ROW.

Comment: So, the explanation is great, but not +1 great? ;)

Comment: ASAP i'll give the +1 but now my points is not enough to give +1 :)

Comment: no problem, just kidding :)